# How to plot a non-linear Regression line in R

Tags: r

I have input the following dataset into R:

```
Distance    Overall Average
-9.867344   0.001928728
-8.769583   0.0011855
-8.667573   0.001401361
-8.373794   0.001514139
-7.443686   0.001046918
-3.862468   0.000790981
1.817748    0.000945557
2.5333892   0.000940648
4.190557    0.001649773
```

When plotted onto a scatter plot these give a U-Shaped curve so I am trying to plot a non-linear regression 'line' onto the plot. 
[Plot of the original Data showing the U-shaped curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0oUt.png)

I saw the following example given to a previous question...

```
plot(speed ~ dist, data = cars)
fit1 = lm(speed ~ dist, cars) #fits a linear model
plot(speed ~ dist, data = cars)
abline(fit1) #puts line on plot
fit2 = lm(speed ~ I(dist^2) + dist, cars) #fits a model with a quadratic term
fit2line = predict(fit2, data.frame(dist = -10:130))
```

However, after trying this multiple times I am consistently being shown the same error comment:

```
plot(Ammonia$Overall.Average~Ammonia$Distance)
fit1=lm(Ammonia$Overall.Average~Ammonia$Distance)
abline(fit1)
fit2=lm(Ammonia$Overall.Average ~ I(Ammonia$Distance^2) + Ammonia$Distance)
fit2line = predict(fit2, data.frame(Ammonia$Distance = 9,3))
Error: unexpected '=' in "fit2line = predict(fit2, data.frame(Ammonia$Distance ="
```

I am also not sure if "9,3" are the right numbers to have put in here as I'm not really sure where the example I followed got their numbers from.

Comment: I think the problem might be that you are using $ notation in the formula rather than using a data argument
so try fit1=lm(Overall.Average~Distance, data  = Ammonia) etc

Comment: @RichardTelford Formulas work fine with `$`. The actual problem is that OP is using the `data.frame` function and tries to assign `Ammonia$Distance` as the column name. The error can easily be replicated by typing something like `data.frame(b$x = 10)` into a new R session.

Comment: @laterow - I should have been more specific, the use of the $ notation in the formula was causing problems in the predict function
predict(fit2, data.frame(Distance = 9)) would work fine

Comment: @RichardTelford I have tried your suggested solution of removing the $ from the predict function and am now getting different errors:

'plot(Ammonia$Overall.Average~Ammonia$Distance)'

'fit2=lm(Ammonia$Overall.Average~I(Ammonia$Distance^2)+Ammonia$Distance)'

'fit2line=predict(fit2, data.frame(Distance=9))'

'Warning message: 'newdata' had 1 row but variables found have 9 rows'

Comment: @LaterowI'm not quite sure what you mean by your solution, I tried this..fit2line=predict(fit2, data.frame(b$x=10))
Error: unexpected '=' in "fit2line=predict(fit2, data.frame(b$x=" but I've got a feeling that's not what you were suggesting? Sorry, very new to R

Comment: try: 
plot(Overall.Average~Distance, data = Ammonia)
fit1=lm(Overall.Average~Distance, data = Ammonia)
abline(fit1)
fit2=lm(Overall.Average ~ I(Distance^2) + Distance, data  = Ammonia)
fit2line = predict(fit2, data.frame(Distance = 9))

Comment: @RichardTelford That worked without an error but how do I then get that line onto my graph?

Comment: @RichardTelford the lines function works without error but doesn't plot any line on the graph?

Comment: can you give the code you used?

Comment: plot(Overall.Average~Distance, data=Ammonia)
fit2=lm(Overall.Average~I(Distance^2)+Distance, data=Ammonia)
fit2line = predict(fit2, data.frame(Distance=9))
lines(fit2line)

Comment: OK, you need to give both the x and y value for lines, and it will need at least 2 points. For a nonlinear fit you will need several.
newD <- seq(min(Ammonia$Distance), max(Ammonia$Distance, length = 100) 
fit2line <- predict(fit2, data.frame(distance = newD))
lines(newD, fit2line)

Comment: It worked!!! Thanks for all your help @RichardTelford

Comment: @RichardTelford I'm trying to replicate this on another data set but wondering what the 'length = 100' means?

Comment: Change it to a different number and see what happens to newD